# How do I see version numbers of my apps on iOS?

Tags: ios, applications, system-information

The App Store is telling me I have an update to an app that is currently installed, and it shows the new version. How do I see the version I currently have?

The closest thing I was able to find is a Cydia app called [AppInfo](http://thetechjournal.com/electronics/iphone/get-information-about-apps-installed-on-your-device-with-appinfo.xhtml), but I can't jailbreak yet (nor am I comfortable doing so).

Is there another way? The ideal answer could be done on the device itself, but barring that, I'm ok with transferring something to my Mac and viewing it there (e.g. with iExplorer).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On your iPhone, before iOS 14:

- Open **Settings** -> **General** -> **Usage** -> **Storage**

With iOS 14 and above:

- Open **Settings** -> **General** -> **iPhone Storage**

Then wait till it shows the list of apps, and select the app you're interested in.

This will show the app version but not the build number.

This works only for third party apps. The Apple provided stock apps will not show this information.

---

In iOS 11 the method described also works for Apple provided stock apps.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. I thought I tried that, but I might've clicked on a built-in app instead one from the Store. Built-in ones don't show the version.

Comment: Yes, stock apps do not show the version. I have updated the answer with this information.

Comment: Still works on iOS 13!

Comment: Note that iOS 12.1.14 uses Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage

Comment: I have to say this is a pretty indirect and tangential place to make this information visible. They should have kept the behavior seen in MacOS where each app had its own About page to look up this information.

Answer (score 11):

Settings / General / iPhone Storage / <app_name>

Comment: Sadly doesn't seem to display a version number for the built-in Apple apps.

Answer (score 1):

To identify Applications Version on iOS

Step A

1. Open Settings
2. Click General

[image]

Step B

1. Click iPhone Storage

[image]

Step C

1. Either Allow Apps to load or search for APP
2. Select App

[image]
[image]

Step D

App Version is to the right of Application Icon

[image]